# Как при создании комментария к посту вк сделать предпоказ ссылки?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Нужно чтобы при создании комментария к посту Vk показывался предпоказ ссылки
Если вставлять ссылку руками, то все получается:

[image: example]

Если же делать программно, то предпоказа нет:

```
vk.wall.createComment(
    post_id=post_id, message=msg_comment, attachments='https://google.com'
)
```

Хотя это работает если создается не комментарий, а пост:

```
vk.wall.post(message=msg_post, attachments='https://google.com')
```

В документации Vk Api по методу wall.post сказано, что нужно передать просто ссылку в attachments и все будет хорошо.

[image: ex]

Почему тогда не работает тоже самое для создания комментария?